# How to configure socket connect timeout

Tags: c#, sockets, timeout

When the Client tries to connect to a disconnected IP address, there is a long timeout over 15 seconds... How can we reduce this timeout? What is the method to configure it?

The code I'm using to set up a socket connection is as following:

```
try
{
    m_clientSocket = new Socket(
         AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
         SocketType.Stream,
         ProtocolType.Tcp);

    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(serverIp);
    int iPortNo = System.Convert.ToInt16(serverPort);
    IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, iPortNo);

    m_clientSocket.Connect(ipEnd);
    if (m_clientSocket.Connected)
    {
        lb_connectStatus.Text = "Connection Established";
        WaitForServerData();
    }
}
catch (SocketException se)
{
    lb_connectStatus.Text = "Connection Failed";
    MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem by using Socket.ConnectAsync Method instead of Socket.Connect Method.
After invoking the Socket.ConnectAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs), start a timer (timer_connection), if time is up, check whether socket connection is connected (if(m_clientSocket.Connected)), if not, pop up timeout error.

```
private void connect(string ipAdd,string port)
    {
        try
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs e=new SocketAsyncEventArgs();


            m_clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(serverIp);
            int iPortNo = System.Convert.ToInt16(serverPort);
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, iPortNo);

            //m_clientSocket.
            e.RemoteEndPoint = ipEnd;
            e.UserToken = m_clientSocket;
            e.Completed+=new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(e_Completed);                
            m_clientSocket.ConnectAsync(e);

            if (timer_connection != null)
            {
                timer_connection.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                timer_connection = new Timer();
            }
            timer_connection.Interval = 2000;
            timer_connection.Tick+=new EventHandler(timer_connection_Tick);
            timer_connection.Start();
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            lb_connectStatus.Text = "Connection Failed";
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }
private void e_Completed(object sender,SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        lb_connectStatus.Text = "Connection Established";
        WaitForServerData();
    }
    private void timer_connection_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!m_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Timeout");
            //m_clientSocket = null;

            timer_connection.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When the timer stops, you show an error message right? How does this stop your TCP stack from actually connecting. Imagine a scenario, where a remote host is more than 2 seconds away i.e. rto > 2. Your timer will stop and you will print the error message. However, TCP is not controlled by your timer. It will still try to connect and may connect successfully after 2 seconds. Does C# provide a facility to cancel "connect" requests or a close on socket. Your timer solution is equal to checking after 2 second whether connection succeeded.

Comment: I found this : http://splinter.com.au/blog/?p=28 
Looks like this is the way. It is similar to yours but I think it does what I explained above.

Comment: When it times out, you should call m_clientSocket.Close();

Comment: Update, my blog link as referenced by aditya has changed: http://splinter.com.au/opening-a-tcp-connection-in-c-with-a-custom-t

Comment: I'd re-write the logic related to the call "timer_connection.Dispose();". The timer_connection object reference is possibly used after the object is disposed.

Answer (score 172):

I found this. Simpler than the accepted answer, and works with .NET Framework v2

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

// Connect using a timeout (5 seconds)

IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginConnect( sIP, iPort, null, null );

bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne( 5000, true );

if ( socket.Connected )
{
    socket.EndConnect( result );
}
else 
{
     // NOTE, MUST CLOSE THE SOCKET

     socket.Close();
     throw new ApplicationException("Failed to connect server.");
}
 
//...
```

Comment: OK, little input on this one-- I like this and its a lot less code.. however the !success isnt the correct condition.  Instead, add if (!_socket.Connected)  and it works much better.  Ill give it a +1 for the less is more aspect.

Comment: This is very useful, as it seems. My issue is that I'm not sure what should I set as timeout. To big and checking process will take some time if I'm doing multiple ports. Too small it might be not enough to get the response. What you suggest?

Comment: Depends on your two end points. If they are both in a datacenter, then 1 second should be plenty, 3 for good measure, 10 to be kind.  If one end is on a mobile device, such as a smartphone, then you might be looking at 30 seconds.

Comment: Another thing too look out for... If instead of putting `null` in for the `callback` and you plan to `EndConnect()`, if the socket has been `closed` then this will give you an exception. So make sure you check...

Comment: What if I want to INCREASE the timeout rather than to DECREASE it? I think async approach just lets you make the code not wait for 20 seconds (the internal timeout set in socket connect). But in case if the connection takes longer, the BeginConnect will stop anyway. Or, does BeginConnect internally waits forever? I have a very slow connection when sometimes it's required for up to 30-40 seconds to connect, and timeouts at 21st second occur very often.

Comment: Wonderful! It works without exceptions yet not documented officially

Comment: From personal experience performance goes rogue with 'high' traffic. Might work in most cases though.

Comment: @TravisWhidden Can confirm, this is very important!  In my experience, if the end point can be reached, but there is no server on the endpoint able to receive the connection, then `AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne` will be signaled, but the socket will remain unconnected.

Comment: I would think that's one more reason not to rely on the Boolean returned.  Instead, I set a nullable one to null before connecting, and set it to the status of `socket.Connected`  in a callback routine that should be here (but isn't...why?).  If it goes into the exception block of a `try...catch` in that callback function, you set the Boolean to false there.

Comment: `throw new SocketException(10060);` Connection timed out.

Comment: One should not call BeginConnect without also calling EndConnect - from .NET6 onwards you'll start to go get difficult-to-track-down "unobserved exceptions" if you do this.

Comment: Running two load tests (100 connections spread over 30ms intervals passing multiple packets per session then reconnecting after 60 seconds), one using the blocking call, Connect, and the other using BeginConnect, timeouts are immediately triggered using BeginConnect.  Using the blocking call, I am able to maintain all 100 connections while re-connecting every minute.  The BeginConnect method is not able to successfully pass a single iteration of the performance test.

Answer (score 30):

My take:

```
public static class SocketExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Connects the specified socket.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="socket">The socket.</param>
    /// <param name="endpoint">The IP endpoint.</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">The timeout.</param>
    public static void Connect(this Socket socket, EndPoint endpoint, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var result = socket.BeginConnect(endpoint, null, null);

        bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout, true);
        if (success)
        {
            socket.EndConnect(result);
        }
        else
        {
            socket.Close();
            throw new SocketException(10060); // Connection timed out.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty to handle a condition. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Per comments on top-rated answer, which this looks to be a copy of except that it's made into a `SocketExtension`, you still haven't used `.Connected` to see if you are, and you're not using `socket.Connected = true;` to define `success`.

Answer (score 21):

I just wrote an extension class in order to allow timeouts in connections. Use it exactly as you would use the standard `Connect()` methods, with an extra parameter named `timeout`.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

/// <summary>
/// Extensions to Socket class
/// </summary>
public static class SocketExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Connects the specified socket.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="socket">The socket.</param>
    /// <param name="host">The host.</param>
    /// <param name="port">The port.</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">The timeout.</param>
    public static void Connect(this Socket socket, string host, int port, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        AsyncConnect(socket, (s, a, o) => s.BeginConnect(host, port, a, o), timeout);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Connects the specified socket.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="socket">The socket.</param>
    /// <param name="addresses">The addresses.</param>
    /// <param name="port">The port.</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">The timeout.</param>
    public static void Connect(this Socket socket, IPAddress[] addresses, int port, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        AsyncConnect(socket, (s, a, o) => s.BeginConnect(addresses, port, a, o), timeout);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Asyncs the connect.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="socket">The socket.</param>
    /// <param name="connect">The connect.</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">The timeout.</param>
    private static void AsyncConnect(Socket socket, Func<Socket, AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> connect, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var asyncResult = connect(socket, null, null);
        if (!asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout))
        {
            try
            {
                socket.EndConnect(asyncResult);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            { }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fan of GhostDoc, are ya? ;-) "Asyncs the connect" - classic GhostDoc WTFness.

Comment: :) yes, and sometimes not even a reader of what's been generated.

Comment: Better socket.EndConnect than socket.Close ?

Comment: The `socket.EndConnect` takes ~10 seconds to close so the function returns not after the time span but after timespan+endConnect time

Answer (score 12):

it might be too late but there is neat solution based on Task.WaitAny (c# 5 +) :

```
 public static bool ConnectWithTimeout(this Socket socket, string host, int port, int timeout)
        {
            bool connected = false;
            Task result = socket.ConnectAsync(host, port);               
            int index = Task.WaitAny(new[] { result }, timeout);
            connected = socket.Connected;
            if (!connected) {
              socket.Close();
            }

            return connected;
        }
```

Comment: Does any "ConnectAsync" overload accept host and port?

Comment: @marsh-wiggle, "ConnectAsync" method has 4 overloads https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.7.2 Please look Extension Methods section

Comment: @OlegBondarenko ok, not avaliable for .net 4.5.1. I have to wrap it myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I dont program in C# but in C, we solve the same problem by making the socket non-blocking and then putting the fd in a select/poll loop with a timeout value equal to the amount of time we are willing to wait for the connect to succeed.

I found [this](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=312668) for Visual C++ and the explanation there also bends towards the select/poll mechanism I explained before.

In my experience, you cannot change connect timeout values per socket. You change it for all (by tuning OS parameters).

Answer (score 2):

Check this out on [MSDN](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/41602-TcpClient-or-Socket-Connect-timeout/).  It does not appear that you can do this with the implemented properties in the Socket class.  

The poster on MSDN actually [solved his problem](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/41602-TcpClient-or-Socket-Connect-timeout/?CommentID=41694) using threading.  He had a main thread which called out to other threads which run the connection code for a couple seconds and then check the Connected property of the socket:

> I created another method wich actually
>   connected the socket ... had the main
>   thread sleep for 2 seconds and then
>   check on the connecting method (wich
>   is run in a separate thread)  if the
>   socket was connected good otherwise
>   throw an exception "Timed out " and
>   that;s all. Thanks again for the
>   repleies.

What are you trying to do, and why can't it wait for 15-30 seconds before timing out?

Answer (score 2):

I had the Same problem when connecting to a Socket and I came up with the below solution ,It works Fine for me.
`

```
private bool CheckConnectivityForProxyHost(string hostName, int port)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostName))
               return false;

           bool isUp = false;
           Socket testSocket = null;

           try
           {

               testSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
               IPAddress ip = null;
               if (testSocket != null && NetworkingCollaboratorBase.GetResolvedConnecionIPAddress(hostName, out ip))//Use a method to resolve your IP
               {
                   IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);

                   isUp = false;
//time out 5 Sec
                  CallWithTimeout(ConnectToProxyServers, 5000, testSocket, ipEndPoint);

                       if (testSocket != null && testSocket.Connected)
                       {
                           isUp = true;
                       }
                   }

               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               isUp = false;
           }
           finally
           {
               try
               {
                   if (testSocket != null)
                   {
                       testSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                   }
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {

               }
               finally
               {
                   if (testSocket != null)
                       testSocket.Close();
               }

           }

           return isUp;
       }


 private void CallWithTimeout(Action<Socket, IPEndPoint> action, int timeoutMilliseconds, Socket socket, IPEndPoint ipendPoint)
       {
           try
           {
               Action wrappedAction = () =>
               {
                   action(socket, ipendPoint);
               };

               IAsyncResult result = wrappedAction.BeginInvoke(null, null);

               if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeoutMilliseconds))
               {
                   wrappedAction.EndInvoke(result);
               }

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {

           }
       }

  private void ConnectToProxyServers(Socket testSocket, IPEndPoint ipEndPoint)
       {
           try
           {
               if (testSocket == null || ipEndPoint == null)
                   return;

                   testSocket.Connect(ipEndPoint);

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {

           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked with Unity and had some problem with the BeginConnect and other async methods from socket.

There is something than I don't understand but the code samples before doesn't work for me.

So I wrote this piece of code to make it work. I test it on an adhoc network with android and pc, also in local on my computer. Hope it can help.

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class ConnexionParameter : Guardian
{
    public TcpClient client;
    public string address;
    public int port;
    public Thread principale;
    public Thread thisthread = null;
    public int timeout;

    private EventWaitHandle wh = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public ConnexionParameter(TcpClient client, string address, int port, int timeout, Thread principale)
    {
        this.client = client;
        this.address = address;
        this.port = port;
        this.principale = principale;
        this.timeout = timeout;
        thisthread = new Thread(Connect);
    }


    public void Connect()
    {
        WatchDog.Start(timeout, this);
        try
        {
            client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(address), port);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogWarning("Unable to connect service (Training mode? Or not running?)");
        }
        OnTimeOver();
        //principale.Resume();
    }

    public bool IsConnected = true;
    public void OnTimeOver()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!client.Connected)
            {
                    /*there is the trick. The abort method from thread doesn't
 make the connection stop immediately(I think it's because it rise an exception
 that make time to stop). Instead I close the socket while it's trying to
 connect , that make the connection method return faster*/
                IsConnected = false;

                client.Close();
            }
            wh.Set();

        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogWarning("Connexion already closed, or forcing connexion thread to end. Ignore.");
        }
    }


    public void Start()
    {

        thisthread.Start();
        wh.WaitOne();
        //principale.Suspend();
    }

    public bool Get()
    {
        Start();
        return IsConnected;
    }
}


public static class Connexion
{


    public static bool Connect(this TcpClient client, string address, int port, int timeout)
    {
        ConnexionParameter cp = new ConnexionParameter(client, address, port, timeout, Thread.CurrentThread);
        return cp.Get();
    }

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653588/timeout-at-acceptsocket
    public static Socket AcceptSocket(this TcpListener tcpListener, int timeoutms, int pollInterval = 10)
    {
        TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutms);
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        while (stopWatch.Elapsed < timeout)
        {
            if (tcpListener.Pending())
                return tcpListener.AcceptSocket();

            Thread.Sleep(pollInterval);
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

and there a very simple watchdog on C# to make it work:

```
using System.Threading;

public interface Guardian
{
    void OnTimeOver();
}

public class WatchDog {

    int m_iMs;
    Guardian m_guardian;

    public WatchDog(int a_iMs, Guardian a_guardian)
    {
        m_iMs = a_iMs;
        m_guardian = a_guardian;
        Thread thread = new Thread(body);
        thread.Start(this);
    }


    private void body(object o)
    {
        WatchDog watchdog = (WatchDog)o;
        Thread.Sleep(watchdog.m_iMs);
        watchdog.m_guardian.OnTimeOver();
    }

    public static void Start(int a_iMs, Guardian a_guardian)
    {
        new WatchDog(a_iMs, a_guardian);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is like FlappySock's answer, but I added a callback to it because I didn't like the layout and how the Boolean was getting returned.  In the comments of that answer from Nick Miller:

> In my experience, if the end point can be reached, but there is no server on the endpoint able to receive the connection, then AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne will be signaled, but the socket will remain unconnected

So to me, it seems relying on what is returned can be dangerous - I prefer to use `socket.Connected`.  I set a nullable Boolean and update it in the callback function.  I also found it doesn't always finish reporting the result before returning to the main function - I handle for that, too, and make it wait for the result using the timeout:

```
private static bool? areWeConnected = null;

private static bool checkSocket(string svrAddress, int port)
{
    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(svrAddress), port);
    Socket socket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    int timeout = 5000; // int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["socketTimeout"].ToString());
    int ctr = 0;
    IAsyncResult ar = socket.BeginConnect(endPoint, Connect_Callback, socket);
    ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne( timeout, true );

    // Sometimes it returns here as null before it's done checking the connection
    // No idea why, since .WaitOne() should block that, but it does happen
    while (areWeConnected == null && ctr < timeout)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        ctr += 100;
    } // Given 100ms between checks, it allows 50 checks 
      // for a 5 second timeout before we give up and return false, below

    if (areWeConnected == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private static void Connect_Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    areWeConnected = null;
    try
    {
        Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        areWeConnected = socket.Connected;
        socket.EndConnect(ar);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      areWeConnected = false;
      // log exception 
    }
}
```

**Related:**  [How to check if I'm connected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871601/how-to-check-if-im-connected)

Answer (score -1):

I have tried with dotnet 6, and after accepting a connection dotnet allows you to set the timeout.

```
          Socket clientSocket = listener.Accept();
          clientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
```

and the you have to manage with `Receive`

```
  try
         {
         int numByte = clientSocket.Receive(bytes);
         data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, numByte);
         break;
         }
  catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException e)
        {
         clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
         clientSocket.Close();
         goto NewSocket;
         }
```

Source: [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.ttl?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score -8):

There should be a ReceiveTimeout property in the Socket class.

[Socket.ReceiveTimeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx)

Comment: I tried. It just doesn't work. I added  m_clientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000; before invoked the  m_clientSocket.Connect(ipEnd). However, it still waits around 15-20 secs before popup the exception message.

Comment: This sets the timeout for when the socket is receiving data after the connection has been made.

Comment: Can't use `ReceiveTimeout` - this is strictly for when receiving with `BeginReceive` and `EndReceive`.  There's no equivalent for when you are just seeing if you are connected.

Comment: Incidentally, I find this works perfectly....unless I unplug my USB ethernet adapter. Like it can handle some types of timeouts but not others.