# Find server listening on a specific port on local network

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I have a server application. I also have a client application. I am able to establish a tcp connection between the applications when both applications happen to be on the same network. so let's say that the computer running the server application is listening from new connections on port 2121 and it has the LAN ip address 192.168.0.120.  On a different computer running the client application I will be able to establish a connection by providing port number 2121 and ip address 192.168.0.120.

Is there a way to find all computers on a network that are listening on port 2121?

One algorithm that I am thinking now is like:

- get ip address of current computer and lets say it comes out as 192.168.0.145.
- now most likely the server will be listening on ip addresss 192.168.0.?
- then ping 192.168.0.1 on port 2121 then 192.168.0.2 on port 2121 ... and then keep going.

I don't know if that method is efficient. moreover there might be a possibility that the server happens to be listening on ip address 192.168.1.x

So what changes will I have to make to my server and client application so that the client is able to  find all the servers listening on port 2121?

Comment: Are you using WCF for communications and .NET 4 ?

Comment: *Why* do you want to find all the servers? Why do you even need more than one? Because of load-balancing? Or as a backup when one of them is down?

Comment: I have this application where I am able to sync files between to computers. maybe someone else uses my application and two servers happen to be on the same network. I just want it to make it simple for users to be able to locate the server...

Answer (score 7):

The algorithm you proposed is the one you need. One problem is in the dynamic generation of the candidate IP addresses.

Normally, **the possible IP address range is the one given by the subnet mask** ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork ). More exactly, the part of the IP that change is that part when in the subnet mask you have 0bits (always at the end of mask).

In your example:

- if the mask is 255.255.255.0, then your possible ip address range is
  192.168.0.*.
- if the IP can also be 192.168.**1**.* then probably the mask should be 255.255.**0**.0
- you can also have mask like 255.255.255.128 and the range would be 192.18.1.[1-126]. You can practically learn more using http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

The only **other possibilities which cause your problem** that I see to have these distinct ranges are:

- you have more DHCP servers in your network, which is really bad as you will have "race conditions". The solution here is to fix your infrastructure by removing all but 1 DHCP server
- you have manually set IP addresses (probably on laptops). The solution is to change to DHCP (if you need a specific IP that will always be assigned to a specific computer, use static DHCP)

---

Getting back to the problem of finding the problem of checking if "something" is listening on a specific port, the ICMP protocol is not the best here, as the majority of firewalls filter both the broadcast ICMP and single ICMP. **If we are truly talking of a server, chances are you had to manually open the port you are looking for.** Also, **even if all computers respond, you still don't know if they host your wanted service**.

---

The solution below involves *computing the possible range of candidate IP addresses*. After that *you iterate through them to see if you can connect to your port*.

In this implementation I test sequentially, which proves to be very slow as the timeout for connect is 30 seconds if the host is not on. For several hundred candidates, it doesn't sound too good. However, if the majority of host are available (even if they don't host your service), everything will go several times faster.

You can **improve the program by either finding out how to decrease this timeout** (I couldn't find out how in my allocated time) or to **use a custom timeout as presented in** [How to configure socket connect timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062035/how-to-config-socket-connect-timeout-in-c) . You could also use multi-threading and adding the address that worked in a thread-safe collection and work with it from there.

Also, **you could try pinging (ICMP) before, but you could miss valid servers**.

---

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        int wantedPort = 21;    //this is the port you want

        byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("type msg here");


        foreach (NetworkInterface netwIntrf in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Interface name: " + netwIntrf.Name);

            Console.WriteLine("Inteface working: {0}", netwIntrf.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up);

            //if the current interface doesn't have an IP, skip it
            if (! (netwIntrf.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Count > 0))
            {
                break;
            }

            //Console.WriteLine("IP Address(es):");

            //get current IP Address(es)
            foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation uniIpInfo in netwIntrf.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
            {
                //get the subnet mask and the IP address as bytes
                byte[] subnetMask = uniIpInfo.IPv4Mask.GetAddressBytes();
                byte[] ipAddr = uniIpInfo.Address.GetAddressBytes();

                // we reverse the byte-array if we are dealing with littl endian.
                if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                {
                    Array.Reverse(subnetMask);
                    Array.Reverse(ipAddr);
                }

                //we convert the subnet mask as uint (just for didactic purposes (to check everything is ok now and next - use thecalculator in programmer mode)
                uint maskAsInt = BitConverter.ToUInt32(subnetMask, 0);
                //Console.WriteLine("\t subnet={0}", Convert.ToString(maskAsInt, 2));

                //we convert the ip addres as uint (just for didactic purposes (to check everything is ok now and next - use thecalculator in programmer mode)
                uint ipAsInt = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ipAddr, 0);
                //Console.WriteLine("\t ip={0}", Convert.ToString(ipAsInt, 2));

                //we negate the subnet to determine the maximum number of host possible in this subnet
                uint validHostsEndingMax = ~BitConverter.ToUInt32(subnetMask, 0);
                //Console.WriteLine("\t !subnet={0}", Convert.ToString(validHostsEndingMax, 2));

                //we convert the start of the ip addres as uint (the part that is fixed wrt the subnet mask - from here we calculate each new address by incrementing with 1 and converting to byte[] afterwards 
                uint validHostsStart = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ipAddr, 0) & BitConverter.ToUInt32(subnetMask, 0);
                //Console.WriteLine("\t IP & subnet={0}", Convert.ToString(validHostsStart, 2));

                //we increment the startIp to the number of maximum valid hosts in this subnet and for each we check the intended port (refactoring needed)
                for (uint i = 1; i <= validHostsEndingMax; i++)
                {
                    uint host = validHostsStart + i;
                    //byte[] hostAsBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(host);
                    byte[] hostBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(host);
                    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                    {
                        Array.Reverse(hostBytes);
                    }

                    //this is the candidate IP address in "readable format" 
                    String ipCandidate = Convert.ToString(hostBytes[0]) + "." + Convert.ToString(hostBytes[1]) + "." + Convert.ToString(hostBytes[2]) + "." + Convert.ToString(hostBytes[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Trying: " + ipCandidate);


                    try
                    {
                        //try to connect
                        sock.Connect(ipCandidate, wantedPort);
                        if (sock.Connected == true)  // if succesful => something is listening on this port
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\tIt worked at " + ipCandidate);
                            sock.Close();
                            sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                        }
                        //else -. goes to exception
                     }
                    catch (SocketException ex)
                    { 
                        //TODO: if you want, do smth here
                        Console.WriteLine("\tDIDN'T work at " + ipCandidate);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        sock.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

(sorry for my bad english) I am actually needing something similar to this and just found out about multicast. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/multicast.aspx) you can find an article and example. The sample app from the article worked fine on my lan. I do not know exactly how it works but maybe you can *multicast* something from the client and have the server(s) to respond with its IP? Or if that do not work, have the server *multicasting* his IP in a timed interval should do it. Sorry for the lack of informations, i just learned about this :)

Answer (score 1):

An option i am not seeing beeing discussed here is to have a Master Server.

The idea is quite simple: A server where your application's server can register and where you application clients can get a list of active servers.

1. Server A is loaded and imediatly sends a hello message to the Master Server
2. Server B is loaded and sends an hello message to the Master Server
3. Both Server A and B keep sending hello's to Master Server every X Minutes so he knows they are still on
4. Client A is loaded - Needs to issue command - asks Master Server for List of Active Servers - Picks a server from the list - issues command

Things to keep in mind:

1. Master Server must be on a known address / port - either fixed ip or get ip throw well known ServerName
2. Purpose of Master Server is simply register servers and supply clients with their addresses - At first glance i see no other service it could provide your application

If any server is as good as any other for your application, i would advise the list to be ordered according to timestamp of last hello message received from that server - that way client will have at the top of that list the server most likelly to still be up (since it reported beeing up last) and can go down the list subsequentially.

More over, every time the Master Server receives an hello that list changes, so every so often client requests will get a different server list and use a different preferencial server, relieving load on servers accross the board.

Comment: Also this makes it possible for you application servers to use different ports if that ever becomes an issue (as they can register that with the Master Server and clients will know from the Master Server's server list and find your servers. - Only the Master Server (I probably should have called it Registration Server instead) must be on a known port that can't change

Answer (score 1):

can't you use the same method as when you get your ip.

let the client send a broadcast - if no response wait 
server receive broadcast and send one back with its own ip.
 
now the client know that the server is out there and on what ip.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a single server. If you can guarantee that the server location (ip address and port) is constant (or can be looked up) then each client application can 'register' with the server by connecting to it and informing the server about the ip address and local port to call back.

Comment: Yeah I can also do a mac reservation by the router to make sure the server always has the same ip address but that was not my question @philipp schmid. I know how to establish the connection. I just want to add a feature to my application where the client is able to find the server without having to look for it and since both computers are on the same network I assume it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

ICMP Ping does not determine if a computer is listening on a specific port, only if the computer is configured to response to a ping.  ICMP is a protocol, different then TCP or UDP.  It's only use for you would be to determine if an IP Address is use, and even then is becoming less viable.

You have two options.

1. Have the client constantly check every IP address on your local network and try to open port 2121.  This is not a good option.
2. Have every server send out a ICMP ping to the broadcast address with specific data announcing it is on (and optionally not connected to a client) the never every so often (I would recommend a minute for testing, and 5 minutes minimum for production).  All your software has to do is look for the broadcast ping and connect to the sending IP Address.

Update:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;


private Ping _Ping = new Ping();
private PingOptions _PingOptions = new PingOptions(64, true);
private byte[] _PingID = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MyPingID");
private _PingResponse = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public <classname> //Constructor
{
  _Ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHander(PingCompleted);
}

public void PingCompleted(object Sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        //Status Unknown;
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        //Status Error;
    }
    else if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        // Device Replying
    }
    else
    {
        // Status Unknown
    }
}

public void StartPing(string AddressToPing)
{
  IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(AddressToPing);
  _Ping.SendAsync(ipAddress, 15000, _PingID, _PingOptions, _PingResponse);
}
```

Comment: How do I send a ICMP ping ? that seems to be what I am looking for. thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Lots of misinformation here. ICMP is not becoming 'less viable' all all, this is just fantasy: it has *many* uses that are critical parts of TFP/IP. There is in fact no such thing as 'ICMP ping': it is built on other ICMP features. And there are many more options, including UDP multicast and broadcast, a central Registry, port mapper, ...

Comment: I guess I should have said it is less viable for what the OP wants (but I usually assume people post to give information regarding the question asked). There is no reason for me to post information that is not relevant to the OPs need, such as other things the ICMP protocol can do. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the server send his location to a specific port using UDP, and the client listen to it then the client establish a connection with the server based on the given ip and port.