# Timeout for synchronus connections in system.net.sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I want to provide certain timeout at socket.connect() method , i don't want to use beginConnection method of socket as  synchronous connection to socket is required, and need time out only at connect rather than send and receive.
Is their any way to do so?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4708790/703016).

Comment: this doesnt help as it is a time out for send and recieve data not the one for connect.

Comment: It is. Read it more carefully.