# How to stop a non responsive thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a file transport application that moves files between FTP servers.  As any one time we can have dozens of files on the move.  In order to prevent flooding the FTP servers I have a system of monitor and semaphore locks.

Every so often my FTP client freezes somewhere inside System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive() according to the call stack.  I don't get an exception so can't deal with the problem.  I'd like to cancel the thread as it is blocking other threads that want to use the FTP client.

I've considered starting the method that eventually calls System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive() in a new thread and aborting the thread after a time period but I'm concerned that the sockets will remain open after a thread abort.  Is there a more gracefull way to kill and clean up after a non responsive thread?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062035/how-to-config-socket-connect-timeout-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks but that is nothing like my problem.

Comment: I don't think that thread abort can be safe at all.

Comment: Call `Shutdown` on the underlying `Socket`. This will cause the thread to error out.

Comment: What @DavidSchwartz says, plus why only one FTP client?  Why can each thread not have its own?

Comment: Actually each thread does have it's own FTP Client however, I block to prevent too many clients connecting to the same FTP server at the same time as the servers have a habit of failing to respond under load

Answer (score 4):

No.  There's no safe, reliable way to kill a thread without its cooperation.  The mechanisms that exist can be quite heavy-handed, and/or just don't necessarily work.

- You can attempt to `Interrupt()` the other thread, but that generally only interrupts a thread that's waiting/sleeping or is doing something that could block.  If it's in the middle of something that doesn't involve blocking, it won't even *see*, much less respond to, the interrupt til it tries to block again.  Which, if you have a rogue thread, may very well be "never".
- `Abort()` will *probably* kill a thread, but it is not guaranteed either -- the thread can stubbornly refuse to die.  And even if it does die, it can leave your app domain in a questionable state.  (Suppose the thread is aborted just as it entered a `finally` block.  An exception will be thrown right then and there, and that finally block won't run -- so anything it'd release (locks, native resources, whatever) will remain unreleased.)
- Apparently even unloading the app domain just aborts the threads in it, so the uncertainties of `Thread.Abort` apply -- plus, if it works, it'll also kill every thread in the app domain.
- About the only thing that's *relatively* safe and guaranteed to work is to kill the entire process.  And if you do that, there's no guarantee about the state of external stuff.  You can just guarantee that any resources held will be released/closed/whatever, not that they're in any particular state (like, say, "uncorrupted").

In this case, a better solution might be to receive asynchronously (using the real async stuff (`ReceiveAsync`), not `BeginReceive`/`EndReceive`).  That way the thread isn't blocked in native stuff, and is more easily interruptible (if for some reason you still have to do that; async's benefits include that you don't even need a separate thread just to watch input).

Comment: "real async" as in .NET 4.5 (Visual Studio 2012) and ReceiveAsync?  There's nothing to cancel that either...

Comment: @Peter: There's not much to cancel.  `ReceiveAsync` returns immediately, and when the data's received, the callback you specified is run.  The thread's not blocking on anything.  You can easily say in your callback "if i'm disposed or something, don't do anything".

Comment: I think I misread your post as suggesting using ReceiveAsync is easier to cancel, not that using an asynchronous method would potentially alleviate the need to cancel...

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at setting the [ReceiveTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx)?

Otherwise, you can setup a Watchdog property in each thread and check the status of the Watchdog variable to identify non-responsive threads.

Comment: I don't have access to the Socket.ReceiveTimeout property as it's on the far side of an FTPClient dll.  My problem is not identifying the non responsive threads, though a Watchdog is a good technique.  It's what to do once I have identified the non responsive threads.

Comment: There is no good way to terminate the threads if it is stuck in `Socket.Receive()`. It will most likely leave your program in an unstable state. Is it a commercial or 3rd party FTPClient dll?

Comment: I'm using System.Net.FtpClient from CodePlex as it was recommended.

Comment: According to this page http://netftp.codeplex.com/discussions/273132/ there should be a `ReadTimeout` and `WriteTimeout`, as well as async `BeginConnect()`/`EndConnect()` methods. Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running your thread in a separate process (if possible) and kill it mercilessly. Then OS will release all resources

Comment: Well that would do it.  Data transfer back to the calling app might be nasty

Comment: I am sorry, I fail to follow "Data transfer back to the calling app might be nasty". Do you mean some memory mapped file would not fit the purpose?

Comment: A memory mapped file would do it