# TCP for Radio Networks

Tags: c#, tcp, internet-radio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to config socket connect timeout in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062035/how-to-config-socket-connect-timeout-in-c-sharp)

I have a radio network, which is used to connect about 20 nodes. I am using TCP but problem is that before the ack is received TCP resend its packets. There is delay in network about 10 to 30 second for acknowledgement. My application requirement is reliable communication I cannot use UDP , suggest me the way to teak TCP for delayed and very slow network.