# Timeout at AcceptSocket?

Tags: c#, sockets

Is it possible to `AcceptSocket` on a `TcpListener` object with timeouts so that it is interrupted once in a while ?

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localIP, port);
server.Start();
while (!shuttingDown)
    try
    {
        Socket client = server.AcceptSocket();
        if (client != null)
        {
            // do client stuff
        }
    }
    catch { }
```

---

Trying BeginAccept and EndAccept: How do I end the accepting if there is no client like for 3 seconds ? *(I'm trying to approximate the solution here)*

```
server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(DoAcceptTcpClientCallback), server);
Thread.Sleep(3000);
server.EndAcceptTcpClient(???);
```

Comment: You should implement the listening in a listener thread. You could then simply abort the listener thread. Otherwise, you can use the method TcpListener.BeginAcceptSocket which allows you to implement the listening asynchronously.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code checks if there are new clients establishing a connection. If so `AcceptSocket()` is called. The only problem is server must check often for a quick respond to clients.

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localIP, port);
server.Start();
while (!shuttingDown)
{
    if (server.Pending())
    {
        Socket client = server.AcceptSocket();
        if (client != null)
        {
            // do client stuff
        }
    }
    else
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: I'd be angry to know my web request was stuck for a second for the sake of this solution.

Comment: This answer is effectively exactly the same as Ryan Williams' answer if you set your sleep to 10. I nee no reason for the hate or down-votes.

Comment: It's absolutely impossible for anyone to modify this solution for the sake of angry people. I mean those 4 characters are imprinted in stone. You can't even **think** about changing them.

Comment: The problem with using sleeps when timeouts are already provided is that on average the event will occur halfway through the sleep, so on average the sleep is twice as long as necessary, and the second half of it is literally a waste of time. Use a read timeout. What you mean by 'those four letters' escapes me, but dissatisfied users do indicate a need to rethink the solution. You seem to think there is no other.

Answer (score 3):

I have created the following extension method as an overload for TcpListener.AcceptSocket which accepts a timeout parameter.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Accepts a pending connection request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tcpListener"></param>
    /// <param name="timeout"></param>
    /// <param name="pollInterval"></param>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.TimeoutException"></exception>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Socket AcceptSocket(this TcpListener tcpListener, TimeSpan timeout, int pollInterval=10)
    {
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        while (stopWatch.Elapsed < timeout)
        {
            if (tcpListener.Pending())
                return tcpListener.AcceptSocket();

            Thread.Sleep(pollInterval);
        }
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }
```

Comment: Totally unnecessary. Use a read timeout. That's what it's for.

Answer (score -1):

Just set a read timeout on the listening socket. That causes `accept()` to timeout in the same way that a read timeout happens, whatever that is in C#.