# Is possible to use BeginConnect with sync Send and Receive methods of Socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I use class Socket for communcation. At first I used Connect method, Send and Receive methods of Socket. But later I should set timeout to Connect. According this post [How to configure socket connect timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062035/how-to-configure-socket-connect-timeout) I use BeginConnect, but after that my Receive gives me time out.

Is possible to use BeginnConnect, Send and receive together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronous and asynchronous Connect/Send/Receive methods can be mixed. But you got to take care that you don't do 2 calls at the same time, like Connecting with BeginnConnect and then directly trying to use Receive.

You can use the IAsyncResult to determine if the asynchronous call has finished.

This example works without problems, using a tcp echo server on the same pc:

```
Socket myAsyncConnectSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
myAsyncConnectSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 10;
myAsyncConnectSocket.SendTimeout = 10;
int connectTimeout = 10;
var asyncResult = myAsyncConnectSocket.BeginConnect(
    new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 57005), null, null);
bool timeOut = true;
if (asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(connectTimeout))
{
    timeOut = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Async Connected");
    try
    {
        myAsyncConnectSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test 1 2 3"));
        Console.WriteLine("Sent");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
        myAsyncConnectSocket.Receive(buffer);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        if (se.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut) timeOut = true;
        else throw;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Timeout occured: {0}", timeOut);
```

Take a special look into `asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()` as it blocks the current thread until the asynchronous connect is finished, you have to manage this connectionstate yourself if you want to connect/send/receive on different threads.