# How to Dispose a Socket after ConnectAsync times out?

Tags: c#, sockets, mono

An answer in this post

- [How to configure socket connect timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062035/how-to-configure-socket-connect-timeout)

suggests using a `Timer` to time out a connection attempt using [`ConnectAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538102(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I'm unsure how to handle disposal of the `Socket` if that timeout occurs.

Consider the following example

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint (new IPAddress (new byte []{ 127, 0, 0, 1 }), 9042);
    var socket = new Socket(ep.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    var connectTimeoutMs = 50;
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool> ();
    new Timer ((t) => {
        tcs.SetException(new ConnectionTimeoutException());
        ((Timer) t).Dispose();
    }).Change (connectTimeoutMs, Timeout.Infinite);

    var eventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs { RemoteEndPoint = ep };
    eventArgs.Completed += Finisher (tcs);

    if (socket.ConnectAsync (eventArgs)) {
        // dealt synchronously
    }
    try {
        tcs.Task.Wait (); // actually a ContinueWith 
    } catch (AggregateException e) {
        if (e.InnerException is ConnectionTimeoutException) {
            socket.Dispose (); // is this the appropriate place for this?
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep (10000);
}
public static EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs> Finisher(TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs) {
    return (sender, e) => {
        if (e.SocketError != SocketError.Success) {
            tcs.TrySetException (new SocketException ((int)e.SocketError));
        } else {
            tcs.TrySetResult (true);
        }
        e.Dispose ();
    };
}
class ConnectionTimeoutException : SocketException {
    public ConnectionTimeoutException(): base((int) SocketError.TimedOut){}
}
```

On Mono-3.10.0, if the timeout occurs, this causes a fatal (uncaught) `ObjectDisposedException`

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed.
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect (IAsyncResult result) [0x00016] in /home/user/dev/mono-3.10/mono-3.10.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:1274 
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.ConnectCallback (IAsyncResult ares) [0x00000] in /home/user/dev/mono-3.10/mono-3.10.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/SocketAsyncEventArgs.cs:260 
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.DispatcherCB (IAsyncResult ares) [0x000aa] in /home/user/dev/mono-3.10/mono-3.10.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/SocketAsyncEventArgs.cs:234
```

because the call to

```
socket.Dispose()
```

actually completes the `SocketAsyncEventArgs`, but first validates that the corresponding `Socket` wasn't disposed. [This was "corrected" in newer versions of Mono](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23700), but it got me thinking whether this is the appropriate pattern for timing out a connection attempt on a `Socket`. Is it? And should the `Completed` event be raised on `Dispose` of the underlying `Socket` (with `SocketError.Success`, no less)?

---

Solution looks like

```
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint (new IPAddress (new byte []{ 127, 0, 0, 1 }), 9042);
var socket = new Socket(ep.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
var connectTimeoutMs = 50;
var connectTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                (ipEndPoint, callback, state) => ((Socket)state).BeginConnect(ipEndPoint, callback, state),
                asyncResult => ((Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState).EndConnect(asyncResult),
                ep, socket);
var timeoutTask = Task.WhenAny(connectTask, Task.Delay(Options.connectTimeoutMs));
if (await timeoutTask != connectTask) {
    throw new SocketException((int)SocketError.TimedOut);
}
await connectTask;
```

Comment: If your code will be disposing sockets for which outstanding operations are still in progress, it's your job to catch `ObjectDisposedException` and handle it correctly (e.g. clean up any data associated with the incomplete socket operation).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I can't. As I mentioned, Mono checks for disposed and throws that `ObjectDisposedException` in its own threads, it's not propagated to any place that my application code has access to, which is also why it goes unhandled and kills the process.

Comment: If Mono is calling `EndConnect()` on your behalf, that suggests to me that the `ConnectAsync()` method is provided for compatibility reasons, not because it's actually useful. So, you should just use `BeginConnect()` yourself instead, which should give you direct access to the exception thrown by `EndConnect()`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho So what I have in the `Finisher` should instead be in the `BeginConnect`'s `AsyncCallback`, and also call `EndConnect` explicitly (and handle exceptions)?

Comment: Yes. Or alternatively (not sure if this is available in Mono) consider using `Task.FromAsync()`, which wraps an old APM style call (i.e. `BeginXXX`/`EndXXX`) in a `Task`. Then you wouldn't need to create your own `TaskCompletionSource`. If you did that, I believe the `ObjectDisposedException` would be propagated cleanly to your `ContinueWith()`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho God, that makes for some beautiful code with `Task.WhenAny` and  `Task.Delay`. Thank you!