# Timeout for ConnectEx() in IOCP mode?

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, winsock2

In an IOCP Winsock2 client, after `ConnectEx()` times-out on an unsuccessful connection attempt, the following happens:

1. An "IO completion" is queued to the associated IO Completion Port.
2. `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` returns FALSE.
3. `WSAGetOverlappedResult()` returns `WSAETIMEDOUT`.

What determines the timeout period between calling `ConnectEx()` and 1 above? How can I shorten this timeout period?

I know that it is possible to wait for `ConnectEx()` by passing it a filled-out structure `OVERLAPPED.hEvent = WSACreateEvent()` and then waiting for this event, e.g. with `WaitForSingleObject(Overlapped.hEvent, millisec)` to timeout after no connection has been made for the `millisec` time period. BUT, that solution is outside the scope of this question because it does not refer to the IOCP notification model.

Comment: iocp this is not mode. and timeout value independent from associate you socket with iocp or not

Comment: IOCP is a mode of completing the connection request made to Winsock.  Anyway, what determines the "connect timeout" value of the socket, regardless whether it is associated with the IOCP or not ?

Comment: if be exactly - iocp this is not mode but only way how you get notification when io operation complete. i not know/view socket options which let set connection timeout, but let ask - for what you need this ?

Comment: For fast TCP connection scanner, that detects ONLY quickly-connecting servers.

Comment: The default connect timeout is set by the platform, usually around a minute. You can decrease it, but not increase it, by using non-blocking mode and `select()`.

Comment: not sure are exist some option (say via `setsockopt`) which let you set timeout, but possible ofcourse control this manual. say create timer for socket and start it after call `ConnectEx` or use `CreateTimerQueueTimer`

Comment: Or continue using an Event object, use RegisterWaitForSingleObject() to wait on it, and if connected before it elapses then cancel the wait, otherwise call CancelIoEx on the OVERLAPPED

Comment: Which method is easier on system resources?  The one using `CreateTimerQueueTimer()` or the one using `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunatelly look like no built-in option for set socket connect timeout. how minimum i not view this and based on this question - [How to configure socket connect timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062035/how-to-configure-socket-connect-timeout) - nobody not view too.

one possible solution pass event handle to I/O request and if we got `ERROR_IO_PENDING` - call [`RegisterWaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerwaitforsingleobject) for this event. if this call will be successful - our [`WaitOrTimerCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/a47354e2-c665-41f8-8661-ab16ac966243) callback function will be called - or because I/O will be complete (with any final status) and at this moment event (which we pass both to I/O request and [`RegisterWaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerwaitforsingleobject)) will be set or because timeout (*dwMilliseconds*) expired - in this case we need call [`CancelIoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/cancelioex-func) function.

so let say we have `class IO_IRP : public OVERLAPPED` which have reference counting (we need save pointer to `OVERLAPPED` used in I/O request for pass it to [`CancelIoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/cancelioex-func). and need be sure that this `OVERLAPPED` still not used in another new I/O - so yet not free). in this case possible implementation:

```
class WaitTimeout
{
    IO_IRP* _Irp;
    HANDLE _hEvent, _WaitHandle, _hObject;

    static VOID CALLBACK WaitOrTimerCallback(
        __in  WaitTimeout* lpParameter,
        __in  BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired
        )
    {
        UnregisterWaitEx(lpParameter->_WaitHandle, NULL);

        if (TimerOrWaitFired)
        {
            // the lpOverlapped unique here (because we hold reference on it) - not used in any another I/O
            CancelIoEx(lpParameter->_hObject, lpParameter->_Irp);
        }

        delete lpParameter;
    }

    ~WaitTimeout()
    {
        if (_hEvent) CloseHandle(_hEvent);
        _Irp->Release();
    }

    WaitTimeout(IO_IRP* Irp, HANDLE hObject) : _hEvent(0), _Irp(Irp), _hObject(hObject)
    {
        Irp->AddRef();
    }

    BOOL Create(PHANDLE phEvent)
    {
        if (HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL))
        {
            *phEvent = hEvent;
            _hEvent = hEvent;

            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
public:

    static WaitTimeout* Create(PHANDLE phEvent, IO_IRP* Irp, HANDLE hObject)
    {
        if (WaitTimeout* p = new WaitTimeout(Irp, hObject))
        {
            if (p->Create(phEvent))
            {
                return p;
            }

            delete p;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    void Destroy()
    {
        delete this;
    }

    // can not access object after this call
    void SetTimeout(ULONG dwMilliseconds)
    {
        if (RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&_WaitHandle, _hEvent, 
            (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)WaitOrTimerCallback, this, 
            dwMilliseconds, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE|WT_EXECUTEINWAITTHREAD))
        {
            // WaitOrTimerCallback will be called
            // delete self here
            return ;
        }

        // fail register wait
        // just cancel i/o and delete self
        CancelIoEx(_hObject, _Irp);
        delete this;
    }
};
```

and use something like

```
if (IO_IRP* Irp = new IO_IRP(...))
{
    WaitTimeout* p = 0;

    if (dwMilliseconds)
    {
        if (!(p = WaitTimeout::Create(&Irp->hEvent, Irp, (HANDLE)socket)))
        {
            err = ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES;
        }
    }

    if (err == NOERROR)
    {
        DWORD dwBytes;

        err = ConnectEx(socket, RemoteAddress, RemoteAddressLength, 
            lpSendBuffer, dwSendDataLength, &dwBytes, Irp)) ?
                NOERROR : WSAGetLastError();
    }

    if (p)
    {
        if (err == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            p->SetTimeout(dwMilliseconds);
        }
        else
        {
            p->Destroy();
        }
    }

    Irp->CheckErrorCode(err);
}
```

another possible solution set timer via [`CreateTimerQueueTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485(v=vs.85).aspx) and if timer expired - call `CancellIoEx` or close I/O handle from here. difference with event solution - if I/O will be completed before timer expired - the [`WaitOrTimerCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/a47354e2-c665-41f8-8661-ab16ac966243) callback function will be not automatically called. in case event - I/O subsystem set event when I/O complete (after intial pending status) and thanks to that (event in signal state) callback will be called. but in case timer - no way pass it to io request as parameter (I/O accept only event handle). as result we need save pointer to timer object by self and manually free it when I/O complete. so here will be 2 pointer to timer object - one from pool (saved by [`CreateTimerQueueTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485(v=vs.85).aspx)) and one from our object (socket) class (we need it for dereference object when I/O complete). this require reference counting on object which incapsulate timer too. from another side we can use timer not for single I/O operation but for several I/O (because it not direct bind to some I/O)

Comment: You wrote: "Unfortunately it looks like there is no built-in option for setting socket connect timeout"  ...and that IS an grim but acceptable answer to my second question.  As to the presented workaround, I am wondering which method consumes less system resources: the one using CreateTimerQueueTimer() or the one using RegisterWaitForSingleObject() ?

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson - *less system resources* hard to say, also this is depend from windows version - very different implementations. for timer i use [this](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/blob/master/ASIO/io.h#L248). also possible that you link all your sockets object to list and periodic (say 1 per second) check this list for timeout. begin connection time remember in every object. this take less resourses compare this 2 ways